# Smooth Scrolling With Anchor Links

Tags: html, css, smooth-scrolling, codepen

I was wondering if anybody had some simple code that will take my anchor link and smoothly scroll to that section of the page when clicked. Right now, whenever I click my link, it will basically teleport to that section of the webpage without any smooth scroll. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

P.S. I'm doing this in a CodePen

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/ this is done with jquery, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You could try this jQuery script as per [Chris Coyier's article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) and accompanying [codepen](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/dpBMVP):

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Notice in Chris' codepen how the anchor tag hrefs are referencing the relevant h2 id.

Post your codepen and we can have a look.